# Magento 2 - Error Messaging Text Change

Tags: magento2, error, login, inline-translations, js-translation

I'm trying to change a couple error messaging strings on the frontend in 2 places.  First in the regular customer login.

[image]

[image]

And also in the tooltip in the checkout login.  I've tried editing translations, overriding validation js files and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Is the issue specific to Error messages (JS string) only ? Are translations for normal text strings working?

Comment: @Devtype.  Yes.  This is for JS error messaging only.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that validation errors text in `lib/web/mage/validation.js` is like $.mage.__('validation error msg') and not like 'validation error msg'.

If it is not using `$.mage.__()` it will not be translated and you need to override this file in your theme inside `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/web/mage`.

Here you need to use `$.mage.__('')` and put error msgs like  `$.mage.__('Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).')`
Also you can change validation messages here.

Answer (score 0):

Update.

It's my solution, now debugging. Please try.

I already put translation csv.

copy

vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation/validation.js 
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation.js

into your Theme.

ex.

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/web/js/locale/validation

Modify require-config.js

```
var config = {
       map: {
           '*': {
               "validation": 'js/locale/validation/validation',
               'mage/validation': 'js/locale/validation'
           }
       }
};
```

Then, clean up your cache etc. and,

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can ensure that normal translations (non JS) are working. 
For UI components and JS error messages etc I experience that you've to deploy static files for translations to take affect.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear the cache and it should work.

Comment: I've tried changing the translation in my theme's csv file, and deployed the static content and it still doesn't work.  I can verify that text in that csv file is being translated properly.  It seems that changing js validation messaging isn't as simple editing the translation file.